# Pandas calculate average number of words in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

Lets say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,4],
                   'feedback': ['one word', np.nan, np.nan, 'test',
                                'second', np.nan, 'test 2',
                                np.nan,
                                'fourth', 'multiple words', 'test 1 2 3', 'things', np.nan]})

print(df)

    id        feedback
0    1        one word
1    1             NaN
2    1             NaN
3    1            test
4    2          second
5    2             NaN
6    2          test 2
7    3             NaN
8    4          fourth
9    4  multiple words
10   4      test 1 2 3
11   4          things
12   4             NaN
```

I want to calculate some aggregated values:

- row count for each `id`
- number of rows where feedback was provided for each `id`
- average number of words of provided feedback for each
  `id`

My desired output is:

```
   id  count  complete  avg_words
0   1      4         2        1.5
1   2      3         2        1.5
2   3      1         0        NaN
3   4      5         4        2.0
```

I have the following code which accomplishes all but the final point:

```
df.groupby(['id']).agg({'id': 'count',
                        'feedback': ['count', lambda x: len(x)]}).reset_index()
```

Which gives me:

```
  id       feedback         
     count    count <lambda>
0  1     4        2        4
1  2     3        2        3
2  3     1        0        1
3  4     5        4        5
```

Everything is correct apart from the final column (the indexing is also a bit strange, but thats a minor issue)

The lambda function is a placeholder. How do I calculate the average number of words of only the provided feedback for each `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [96]: df.assign(avg_words=df['feedback'].str.split().str.len()) \
    ...:   .groupby('id') \
    ...:   .agg({'id': 'count','feedback': 'count', 'avg_words': 'mean'}) \
    ...:   .rename(columns={'id':'count', 'feedback':'complete'}) \
    ...:   .reset_index()
Out[96]:
   id  count  complete  avg_words
0   1      4         2        1.5
1   2      3         2        1.5
2   3      1         0        NaN
3   4      5         4        2.0
```